# Is it possible to steal cached input values of my browser via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser, security

just while filling in an online form I found out, that auto-completion works for a website I've never visited before. 
Now I wonder if a "cyber-criminal" could place on a fraud web-site a form with several input fields (e.g. account number, password) and simulate keyboard input trying to get/guess the values from my cache via auto-completion. Then she could simulate enter-press and forward data to her server. The form could be even invisible :-(

My question is, could it be possible using JS or some new sophisticated Web-tricks? May be it is even a well-known fraud-trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Those autocomplete options exist somewhere inside the browser but outside of the DOM and javascripts execution enviornment. They would not be available to javascript until after you hit enter and put the information into the html element.  Its not nessecarily impossible, who knows what undiscorved exploits lie out there... but it is not likely and it would (read should) be quickly patched if it was.

Comment: +1 Thanks! So simulating key-event somehow in JS wouldn't involve auto-completer. Good news :-)